# MongoDB and triggers

Tags: mongodb, eventtrigger

I have a post call that inserts records in an Atlas mongodb database, the Atlas service has a trigger active to increment a correlative field (no_hc), then I make a query to retrieve that correlative field with the _id generated in the insert of the document. I put the code below so that they can tell me what I am doing wrong since this code sometimes returns null the field no_hc. Thanks since now

I add information about what I need to execute. I have a collection on which every time a document is added the mongodb server executes a trigger to increment a certain field, the problem is that the findoneandupsert query returns the inserted document with the autoincrement field set to null, since apparently the trigger is executed after the result of findoneandupsert is returned, how can I solve this issue?

```
router.post('/admisionUpsert', (req, res) => {

    admisionUpsert(req.body)
        .then(data => res.json(data))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ error: err + ' Unable to add ' }));

})




async function admisionUpsert(body) {

    let nohc = body.no_hc
    delete body['no_hc'];
    let id;
    let noprot
    await Paciente.findOneAndUpdate(
        { no_hc: nohc },
        {
            apellido: body.apellido,
            nombre: body.nombre,
            sexo: body.sexo,
            no_doc: body.no_doc,
            fec_nac: body.fec_nac,
            calle: body.calle,
            no_tel: body.no_tel,
            email: body.email
        }, {
        new: true,
        upsert: true 
    }
    )
        .then(data => { id = data._id })

    console.log("id pac", id)


    Paciente.findOne({ _id: id }).then(data => { nohc = data.no_hc })


    console.log("nohc pac", nohc)

    await Protocolo.findOneAndUpdate(
        { no_prot: "" },
        {
            cod_os: body.cod_os,
            no_os: body.no_os,
            plan_os: body.plan_os,
            no_hc: nohc,
            sexo: body.sexo,
            medico: body.medico,
            diag: body.diag,
            fec_prot: body.fec_prot,
            medicacion: body.medicacion,
            demora: body.demora
        }, {
        new: true,
        upsert: true 
    }
    )
        .then(data => { id = data._id })

    console.log("id prot", id)



    Protocolo.findOne({ _id: id }).then(data => { noprot = data.no_prot })



    console.log("noprot prot", noprot)


    let practicasProtocolo = []
    body.practicas_solicitadas.map((practica, index1) => {
        practicasProtocolo.push({
            no_prot: noprot,
            cod_ana: practica.codigo,
            cod_os: practica.cod_os,
            estado_administrativo: practica.estado_administrtivo,
            estado_muestra: practica.estado_muestra,
            estado_proceso: practica.estado_proceso,
        })
        practica.parametro.map((parametro, index) => {
            par = parametro.codigo
            tipo_dato = parametro.tipo_dato
            if ((tipo_dato === "numerico") || (tipo_dato === "frase") || (tipo_dato === "codigo")) {
                practicasProtocolo[index1][par] = null;
            }
        })

    })

    console.log(practicasProtocolo)

    practicasProtocolo.map(async (practica, index) => {
        await new Practica(practica).save()
    })


    return { nohc: nohc, noprot: noprot }

}
```